# How to count number of Negative tweets for each state in an Excel file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, twitter

I have an excel file that includes 10K rows, each row has some information for a tweet. For example these columns: Tweet, Date of Tweet, User Name, Retweet Count, ..., **User Location**, **Sentiment**(the value in this column is Positive or negative or neutral), **State**(the value of this column is 50 states of the USA), **Abbreviation** (the value of this column is the abbreviation of state such as CA, NJ, NY,..), **CountofNegative** (this column is empty and I wish to write the number of Negative tweets for each state in this column, so this column will have 50 numbers). 
Problem: count the number of negative tweets for each state or its abbreviation and write in CountofNegative column. 
following is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

file=pd.read_excel("C:/Users/amtol/Desktop/Project/filter.xlsx")
UserLocation= file["User Location"]
Sentiment= file["Sentiment"]
CountofNegative= file["CountofNegative"]
State=file["State"]
Abbreviation= file["Abbreviation"]

for i, (loc,sent) in enumerate(zip(UserLocation, Sentiment)):
    count=0
    for j, (state, abbr) in enumerate(zip(State, Abbreviation)):
        if (loc == state or loc == abbr and sent == "Negative"):
            count=count+1
        file.loc[j+1,"CountofNegative"]=count

print(CountofNegative)

file.to_excel("C:/Users/amtol/Desktop/Project/filter.xlsx")
```

there is no error but when the output file is created, the first 24 values for column "CountofNegative" are zeros and the rest of them are ones(which they are not correct answers). Also, I wanted to test the program by `print(CountofNegative)`, which still nothing happened. (no output). how can I fix my code?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: what do get with `print(i, j)` ? Maybe you should use `if j == i`. Or `for i in range(len(UserLocation))` and `for j in range(len(State))`: or better `for i, (loc,sent) in enumerate(zip(UserLocation, Sentiment)):` and `for j, (state, abbr) in enumerate(zip(State, Abbreviation))` and later `if loc == state or loc == abbr and sent == "Negative')

Comment: @furas thank you for your answer. how can I make the new column? I said ```for i, (loc,sent) in enumerate(zip(UserLocation, Sentiment)):
    count=0
    for j, (state, abbr) in enumerate(zip(State, Abbreviation)):
        if (loc == state or loc == abbr and sent == "Negative"):
            count=count+1
        file.loc[j+1,"CountofNegative"]=count``` but when after this I said ```print(CountofNegative)``` it doesn't print anything. I want to make a new column(say "CountofNegative") in my  current excel file that includes 50 numbers(# of negatives for each state)

Comment: @furas I have edited my question. would you please look at it. maybe now my question is clearer.